# Magento 2: Admin returns 404 using NGINX/PHP 7

Tags: magento2, admin, nginx

I'm attempting to setup a local development version of Magento 2. I'm importing the database from a currently running Magento installation. The site works correctly, but I'm unable to access the admin page.

I'm using PHP 7, Magento 2 and NGINX with the following configuration:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
  server  unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name magento.local;
  set $MAGE_ROOT /home/vagrant/Code/magento;
  include /home/vagrant/Code/magento/nginx.conf.sample;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/magento.dev-error.log error;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/magento.dev-access.log;
}
```

The server returns 404 when visiting /admin (confirmed URL from `php bin/magento info:adminuri`)

There seems to be a fair few issues posted but I've yet to find a solution! Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: when you look into access log , what path nginx is trying to open?

Comment: Have you fixed it in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on vagrant. I have tried it in the past and I have had a lot of trouble. Do not get me wrong, the trouble might be operator error. I have setup Magento 2 on PHP7.0-fpm on digital ocean. I used this configuration: https://goo.gl/NPUiK4. You can also see the "How to Install Magento with Nginx on Ubuntu 16.04" tutorial on my favorite tutorial site: https://goo.gl/xfZJR4 (https://www.howtoforge.com/)

Answer (score 0):

## I recommend you use docker, here is an image to instantly deploy:
https://github.com/fballiano/docker-magento2

I recommend you disable your caches:

```
php -f bin/magento cache:flush
sudo rm -rf var/cache var/generation var/page_cache
php -f bin/magento cache:disable
php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And check your database table `core_config_data` and check if the url is ok on
`web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` search for `%cookie%` and delete all rows.

Give right permissions to folders:

```
chmod -R 777 var
chmod -R 777 pub
chmod -R 777 generated
```

If nothing works then do this command on CLI:

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin_path"
```

Then use `php bin/magento info:adminuri` to check.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for Docker image that works for Magento 2.3 and 2.4 ?